# Explaining $\int_1^{n+1}f(t)dt<f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)<f(1)+ \int_1^n f(t)dt$ in english

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Can someone please explain the intuition behind:

If f is positive, decreasing on the relevant interval, then

$\int_1^{n+1}f(t)dt<f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)<f(1)+ \int_1^n f(t)dt$

Thanks!!

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: kk on it now fewcharsleft

Comment: Okay it's pretty clear now.. But what i did was take $ f(a+1)<\int_a^{a+1} f(t)dt<f(a)$ is this correct?

Comment: That is not true unless $f$ is made up of straight lines connecting the points in question!

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively from drawing the picture, note that

$$f(k)=\int_{k}^{k+1}f(k)dx> \int_k^{k+1}f(x) dx$$

Summing $k=1$ to $n$ gives $$f(1)+f(2)+\cdots f(n)> \int_1^{n+1}f(x)dx$$

On the other hand $$f(k+1)=\int_{k}^{k+1}f(k+1)dx < \int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx$$

Summing from $k=1$ to $n-1$ gives $$f(2)+f(3)+\dots+f(n)<\int_1^{n}f(x)dx$$ and summing $f(1)$ gives what you want. Note the inequalities are true because $f$ is positive and decreasing.

Comment: thank you!! but shouldn't the < sign in the first 2 equations be > instead? edit:nvm you fixed them thanks a lot really gave me insight

Comment: @wwbb90 Yes, I have already changed that. Sorry for the inattention.